# Formula for the kernel of an operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, eigenvector

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and let $O$ be an operator. Obviously $M=O^\dagger O$ is a semi-positive definite operator and $v\in\ker M$ if and only if $v\in\ker O$. Therefore it seems to me that I can find states in the kernel of $O$ with the following ansatz:
$$
\psi=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-tM}\chi \implies \psi\in\ker M\implies \psi\in\ker O
$$
where $\chi\in\mathcal H$ is arbitrary.

In particular, if $H$ is an operator and one was interested in solving the eigenvalue equation
$$
H\psi=\lambda\psi
$$
then a solution is
$$
\psi=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-t(H-\lambda)^\dagger(H-\lambda)}\chi
$$
where $\chi$ is an arbitrary vector.

Are these manipulations fairly standard?

Comment: These manipulations are fairly standard in the physics literature. For the subtleties involved in making this rigorous, an expert in functional analysis would have to weigh in.

Comment: You'd have to provide an argument for the existence of the limit (dominated convergence + functional calculus should take care of that), and then it indeed feels quite routine.

Comment: Also, this will give a $\psi\not= 0$ only if $\chi$ was not orthogonal to the kernel to start with.

Comment: Indeed, in numerical applications, significant effort goes into ensuring that $\chi $ has decent overlap with the state one is interested in.